# How can I retrieve database data and present it in an application

Tags: java, android, database, api

I am currently working on an application in android studio as I am trying to learn how to use it in my spare time, my knowledge is very low so I was hoping I can explain the concept of my app and ask people for some pointers in different techniques I could use. The basic idea of my app is that it works by allowing people to search for a celebrity and it shows a few facts about them, their date of birth etc. I know its nothing special but it is literally a concept to help me improve my android studio knowledge.

My main issue with this is getting the information from the database into the application in an easy to read and presentable way, what sort of things should I be researching to help me achieve this, from my knowledge I believe I would need to set up a scanner to take the users input, then search the database to find the information and then I need to find a way to return the results in a presentable manner.

Apologies if this is too long winded a question, and thank you to everybody who takes the time to read and respond to me.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for some API then check this out this can be help full.

```
https://api-ninjas.com/api/celebrity
```

You can even check if Wikipedia have any API for providing info.

I found this also

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Creating_a_bot#APIs%5Ffor%5Fbots
```

It appears there's also an API for IMDB: `http://www.deanclatworthy.com/imdb/`